# How to call an api from webdriverio test

Tags: webdriver-io

I am beginner to webdriverio. We write automation tests in javascript language. Can anyone please mention how to construct the payload, call an api and get response from api in our automation scripts.Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks/

Answer (score 0):

npm install mocha chai axios

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const axios = require('axios');

describe('API Tests', function () {
  it('should return a successful response', async function () {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.example.com/users');

    expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    expect(response.data).to.be.an('array');
    expect(response.data.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
  });

  it('should return user details by ID', async function () {
    const userId = 1;
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.example.com/users/${userId}`);

    expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    expect(response.data).to.be.an('object');
    expect(response.data.id).to.equal(userId);
    expect(response.data.name).to.be.a('string');
  });

  it('should create a new user', async function () {
    const userData = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'john.doe@example.com',
      age: 30,
    };

    const response = await axios.post('https://api.example.com/users', userData);

    expect(response.status).to.equal(201);
    expect(response.data).to.be.an('object');
    expect(response.data.name).to.equal(userData.name);
    expect(response.data.email).to.equal(userData.email);
    expect(response.data.age).to.equal(userData.age);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**